# Effect of homogenous strong magentic field on a spherical ball: why $H$ is not zero after stopping it?

Tags: electromagnetism

Consider a spherical ball of radius $R$. Firstly, the ball has been magnetized by putting it into a very strong homogeneous magnetic field B while keeping temp = $T_1$. Then, the external magnetic field is removed keeping same temp T1 . After considering this situation. Why H is not equal to zero even though only bound currents r there in this situation?

Comment: your question does not specify the magnetic material; are you asking why the B=B(H) curve is not a single valued function, i.e., what causes hysteresis in a ferromagnet and remanent magnetization?

Comment: Yeah Sir Right ...

Comment: in one word: friction, specifically friction between neighboring domain walls

Comment: Can u bit give a more detail as answer to this problem Sir? I will accept it then